# Finding $x_1+x_2$, where the $x_i$, and $y$ and $z$, are positive integers satisfying $x^2+y^2+z^2=2(xy+1)$ and $x+y+z=2022$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math

> Let $x$, $y$, and $z$ be positive integers satisfying
> $$(x)^2+(y)^2+(z)^2=2(xy+1) \quad\text{and}\quad x+y+z=2022$$
> If $x_1$ and $x_2$ are 2 distinct solutions for $x$, what is the value of $x_1+x_2$?

Attempted to express $(x)^2+(y)^2+(z)^2=2(xy+1)$ as $(x-y)^2+(z)^2=2$, then I'm stuck.

Kindly advise! Thanks!

Comment: Try to apply $(a+b+c)^2$ formula https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fqph.fs.quoracdn.net%2Fmain-qimg-66cd7d713d1fc4a3e01d4484a11f55ab&f=1&nofb=1

Comment: Hint: $(x-y)^2 + z^2 = 2 \implies |x-y|,|z| < \sqrt{2}$. Since $x,y,z$ are positive integers, this means $z = 1$ and ...

Comment: Achillehui above has provided a killer hint. @PongYoPongYo May I ask what the source of this problem is?

Answer (score 1):

So we have , $$(x-y)^2+z^2=2$$

Since $(x,y,z)\in\mathbb Z^+$ we can say $|x-y|=1$ and $z=1$ [ It is because only $1^2 ,1^2$ are the positive integers that sum upto $2$ ]

We have also given that , $$x+y+z=2022$$ $$x+y=2021$$

Now : $$x+y=2021$$ $$x-y=1$$ ​

From these  two linear equations in two variable you'll get  , $$(x,y)\in\{1010,1011\}$$

Here you go you have two distinct values of $x$ .

Answer (score 0):

Considering achile hui comment we have:

$z=1$ and $(x-y)^2=1$ and:

case 1):$\begin {cases}x-y=1\\x+y+1=2022\end{cases}$

which gives $x=1011$ and $y=1010$

case 2):$\begin {cases}x-y=-1\\x+y+1=2022\end{cases}$

which gives $x=1010$ and $y=1011$